# error_log file is created complete rundomly - with some warnings

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code to fetch a row from a table:

```
$sq = "select * from arts where id = :aid limit 1";
$st = $db->prepare($sq);
$st->execute([":aid" => $artid]);
$arow = $st->fetch();
unset($st);

$cat = $arow['cat'];  // line 31
$nick = $arow['nick']; // line 32
$artitle = $arow['title']; // line 33
```

everything works fine but sometimes the `error_log` file is created with the following warnings:

```
Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home/abuenanet/public_html/art.php on line 31
Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home/abuenanet/public_html/art.php on line 32
Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home/abuenanet/public_html/art.php on line 33
```

all the above columns (`cat, nick and title`) are `varchar 255` type

so I delete the `error_log` file and try to reload all pages again - several times - no problem
but again - after some time - I see the `error_log` file is created - with the similar content as above

what is the problem ?

Comment: Problem is that `$arow` is __bool__

Comment: Seems that sometimes, your query matches zero rows and `$st->fetch()` returns `false`. You should make sure it's an array before attempting to use it as one

Comment: @u_mulder  - so why that is NOT the problem 20 times - and next time - it IS the problem ?

Comment: @Phil - what can I do - if it is not array ?

Comment: It happens, if the query return not the record but a bool. To make it stop, CHECK if the result is really an array: `if (is_array($arow)) { /* ok, take the values */ }`

Comment: Either throw an error... `if (!$arow) throw new Exception("arts id $artid not found");` or check it's valid before accessing properties... `if ($arow) { $cat = $arow['cat']; ... }`

Comment: @LarsStegelitz - that means - the page will not be loaded at all. I need to ensure that the above code works each time, and not - sometimes works - sometimes - does not

Comment: Well then go and do some proper debugging, and find out _why_ the query did not return a result set, but a boolean instead.

Comment: @CBroe - of course, your help is real gold

Comment: Am I sensing some irony here, because you feel like this is not enough help at this point? :-) How to figure out _why_ a database query might not have succeeded, is a topic that has been broadly discussed already, so please do some research at this point, if you still don't know how.

Comment: @provance: You work with external data, so you don't need to make sure it works each time... you only need to make sure, that your code handles an error situation properly.
Oh, and a empty result is _not_ a error situation... if the id does not exist, a query for it is still valid!